# Override equal bootstrap classes to use bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC4 project with a `global.css` class and i have added recently bootstrap but result that in my `global.css` class i have some classes that are with the same name so i decided to make a `bootstrap_migration.css` where i put some of the bootstrap classes with the prefix class `.bt` and in my html i put something like `class="bt container"` and everything works fine.

Something like this on my `bootstrap_migration.css`:

```
.bt .jumbotron {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

But do i have a better way to do this?

Comment: 2 ways:1. include the css you want to apply in the latter or 2. use !important to override

Comment: You say everything works fine, so what are you asking? I understand you ware looking for a "better" way, but what else have you tried. How good is your understanding of CSS.

Comment: I dont want to make the bootstrap_migration.css class... it's a pain, that's why i'm asking :)

Comment: If you add your custom CSS after the bootstrap css any classes with the same name in bootstrap will be overridden with the new rules (assuming your specify the same rule types)

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't leave a space in the classes. it should be

```
.bt.jumbotron
```

edit: .bt .jumbotron means that .jumbotron is a child of .bt and do not apply to the same element.

Answer (score 1):

```
.bt.jumbotron
```

Just do not leave spaces between the classes.

Spaces between classes mean that is a child of another.

Comment: Ok.. i should do that. But my question is pointed to not do this at all. I mean.. use the bootstrap original css and my global.css :)

Comment: Then use !important in your css, so you can use along with their bootstrap.

[link](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a new css file like "booststrap-custom.css" and include it after! your bootstrap.css in the html header.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/bootrstrap-custom.css" />
```

Then you can override any classes of bootstrap without touching the bootstrap.css file by simply copying the element definition into your custom file and override your custom attributs there.

Firebug is a very helpful tool to copy the element you want to change.

Example:

If you have your bootstrap.css and it contains:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

And you just want to override the padding for example you insert this to your bootstrap-custom.css

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

and voila, you're done!

This way you dont need to and never ever should touch your original bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the bootstrap file more easily if you use the source bootstrap.[less](http://lesscss.org/) (which [can be downloaded here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), using the [Download source code link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.0.3.zip))

Using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you can nest classes, so that you can apply changes to all the afected classes more easily. And you can make a lot of extra customizations very easily.

If you add the [Web Essentials extension](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) to your Visual Studio, this file will be updated whenever you edit it.

The rest of the solution can't be better done in a better way that you're doing it.